# How to get a scroll bar on a text overlay for a responsive image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap on my project and I have a working text overlay on a responsive image. In fact I have 6 of them (2 rows of 3).

The problem is that the text overflows on small screens. I'd like to use something like:

```
overflow-y: auto
```

But this seems to require a fixed height (and being that this is responsive the height of my images and the overlays are dynamic).

HTML snippet:

```
   <img class="img-responsive box" src="images/landing.jpg">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="purple-overlay">
           <div class="box-inner text-left">
               <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
               <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
               <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
   .purple-overlay {
       position: absolute;
       top:0%;
       left:0%;
       margin: 0%;
       padding: 0%;
       height:100%;
       width:100%;
       background: rgb(163, 39, 185); /* fallback color */
       background: rgba(163, 39, 185, 0.8);
       z-index: 2;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
    }

    .box {
        position:  relative;
        background: rgb(41, 147, 156); /* fallback color */
        background: rgba(41,147,156,0.8);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height:100%;
    }

   .box-inner {
       position:absolute;
       color:black;
       top:5%;
       left:10%;
       margin: 0%;
       padding: 0%;
       padding-right: 10%;
       z-index: 4;
       overflow-y: auto;
   }
```

Anyone got any suggestions (preferably CSS only if poss.)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide a diagram of the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `overflow-y: auto;` on the `.purple-overlay` class so the text won't go outside of the container

Comment: Thanks @niconiiiavec3i. It was as simple as that. You're a star. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as i got the problem,

if you using bootstrap(4) why you didn't write img class like :

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

and why you didn't go with **:before** & **:after** ?

try this :

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/93/65/1d/93651dceeee949437c20171dd3f7cd0e.jpg);
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:" ";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: block;
  z-index:0;
}

.overlay:hover:before{
  display: block;
}

.red:before {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.blue:before {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}

.green:before{
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}

.orange:before {
  background-color: rgba(255,153,0, 0.5);
}

.box * {
    position: relative;
    /* hack */
}

h1 {
  color:white;
}

/** overing **/

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/93/65/1d/93651dceeee949437c20171dd3f7cd0e.jpg);
  position: relative;
}

.overlayHOVER {
  position: relative;
}

.overlayHOVER:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:" ";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: none;
  z-index:0;
}

.overlayHOVER:hover:before{
  display: block;
}

.red:before {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.blue:before {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}

.green:before{
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}

.orange:before {
  background-color: rgba(255,153,0, 0.5);
}

.box * {
    position: relative;
    /* hack */
}

h1 {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<h3>BLOCK the box's</h3>

<div class="box overlay red">
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlay blue">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlay green">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlay orange">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>

<h3>Hover the box's</h3>

<div class="box overlayHOVER red">
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlayHOVER blue">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlayHOVER green">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div class="box overlayHOVER orange">
    <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```